# Not able to read from GreenPlum using Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, greenplum

Please someone could help me to get out of this issue.

I am trying to read from Greenplum using GreenPlum-Spark connector. I used jar greenplum-spark_2.11-1.5.0.jar which I downloaded from https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gpdb/

I am trying to access greenplum from spark-shell and imported jar like below

C:\spark-shell --jars C:\jars\greenplum-spark_2.11-1.6.2.jar

```
scala>val gscReadOptionMap = Map(
      "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://server-ip:5432/db_name",
      "user" -> "user_id",
      "password" -> "pwd",
      "dbschema" -> "schema_name",
      "dbtable" -> "table_name",
      "driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver"
)

scala>val gpdf = spark.read.format("greenplum").options(gscReadOptionMap).load()
```

(or)

```
scala>val gpdf = spark.read.format("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider").options(gscReadOptionMap).load()
```

Resuting in below error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '' does not exist in "schema_name"."table_name" table
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider.createRelation(GreenplumRelationProvider.scala:50)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
  ... 49 elided

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `partitionColumn` option in your `gscReadOptionMap`. For example:

```
val gscOptionMap = Map(
    "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://gsc-dev/tutorial",
    "user" -> "gpadmin",
    "password" -> "changeme",
    "dbschema" -> "faa",
    "dbtable" -> "otp_c",
    "partitionColumn" -> "airlineid"
)
```

For more details, please take a look at the [documentation](https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/1-6/read_from_gpdb.html#lg2s_options).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @frankgh. But is it mandatory to give 'partitionColumn'? I tried with "partitionColumn" -> "col" as per your suggestion though but got the below error:
`data type of 'col' is not supported for partitioning; supported data types are bigint, bigserial, integer, and serial`
But actually the column is numeric type. Any help here?

Comment: The `partitionColumn` is a required option. I suggest you use a different column for the partition column, `numeric/decimal` types are not supported. Only columns of type `bigint`, `bigserial`, `integer`, and `serial` are supported for the `partitionColumn`.